# VSC does not recognize ctrl+c in "Python interactive" session randomly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Basically what the title says, since 1-3 days ago randomly when I press ctrl+c to copy a variable or text or whatever from the python interactive component of the VSC it doesn't copy. I have looked through my shortcut preferences for both ctrl+c and for copy to see if something was interfering but there doesn't seem to be anything. And when I use ctrl+c anywhere else I never have had a problem so it cant be with my keyboard.

I am truly lost and about to go insane from this it is extraordinarily frustrating, so would highly appreciate if anyone more familiar with VSC than me had any thoughts

Comment: try ctrl+shift+c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a developer on the Python extension. There is actually a general VSCode issue affecting copy and paste commands for all webviews (which includes our current notebooks implementation) symptoms are either double paste and cut operations or paste and cut operations not working at all. I believe that this should be resolved in current vscode insiders builds, but I don't believe that the fix is in main VS Code releases yet. This is the VSCode issue tracking the problem.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/101946

Comment: Got it thanks! Any idea when the main release will get updated?

Answer (score 0):

try ctrl + shift + c, maybe that'll work

Comment: I removed that key and moved it to ctrl+c because I thought that would help, it didnt. The thing that really bugs me is that it is seemingly random, sometimes it just stops working and then RANDOMLY starts working again.

Comment: hmmm maybe try to set all shortcuts back to default and see if it works

Comment: problem is I have changed a decent number of them so it will be a bit of a hassle (might have to resort to it though), and this appeared like 1-3 days ago and I havent set anything differently in several months

Comment: So your current 'Terminal: Copy Selection' is set to ctrl + c?

Comment: Yes it is indeed set to that.

Comment: hmm I really don't know, you might have to reset them to the defaults. If you set it to 'ctrl + shift + c' it also still doesn't work?